# Highlight a value if its less than another value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Ok, So this had to be edited because there wasn't enough room to keep commenting between myself and larsAnders.

Basically this has been totally changed since the original post to a more efficient way. This code is working out if the stock we currently hold is lower than our minimum stock requirements, it will highlight the required row to tell me that I need to order more of that specific stocked part.

The First column is what we have in stock (lloblevel)
The Secound column is what we should have in stock at all times (ilevel)

The following is what I have so far

index.php

```
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1px">
<?php for ($i=0; $i<count($lloblevel_val);$i++) { ?>
<tr>
<td>
    <?php if ($lloblevel_val[$i] > $ilevel_val[$i]) {
        echo '<span class="highlight">'.$lloblevel_val[$i].'</span><br/>';
    } else {
        echo $lloblevel_val[$i].'<br/>'; 
    }?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php if ($ilevel_val[$i] > $lloblevel_val[$i]) {
        echo '<span class="highlight">'.$ilevel_val[$i].'</span><br/>';
    } else {
        echo $ilevel_val[$i].'<br/>'; 
    }?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php }//end for ?>
</table>
</body>
```

style.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.highlight {
    background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

levels.php

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("stockexport.csv", "r");
echo $file_handle;

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    print_r($line_of_text);
    $ilevel_val[] = $line_of_text[2];
    $lloblevel_val[] = $line_of_text[1];

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

First few rows of my csv

```
    ItemNumber,ItemTitle,Level,MinimumLevel,InOrderBook,Level_LessOrderBook
    "##### BATTLEFIELD 4 VOUCHER #####","##### BATTLEFIELD 4 VOUCHER #####","108","10","14","94"
"##### BRONZE GAME VOUCHER #####","##### BRONZE GAME VOUCHER #####","170","0","0","170"
"##### CRYSIS 3 VOUCHER #####","##### CRYSIS 3 VOUCHER #####","56","10","2","54"
"##### GOLD GAME VOUCHER #####","##### GOLD GAME VOUCHER #####","56","0","0","56"
"##### RAID 0 (STRIPE) SERVICE #####","##### RAID 0 (STRIPE) SERVICE #####","0","-1","0","0"
"##### RAID 1 (MIRROR) SERVICE #####","##### RAID 1 (MIRROR) SERVICE #####","0","-1","0","0"
"##### SAINTS ROW IV VOUCHER #####","##### SAINTS ROW IV VOUCHER #####","20","2","0","20"
"##### SILVER GAME VOUCHER #####","##### SILVER GAME VOUCHER #####","21","10","24","0"
"##### TOMB RAIDER VOUCHER #####","##### TOMB RAIDER VOUCHER #####","31","10","7","24"
"##### WINDOWS 7 PROFESSIONAL x64 TRIAL INSTALL & UPDATE #####","##### WINDOWS 7
```

Many thanks to larsAnders for the many hours he has taken to help me get this far.

Comment: $line_of_text[3] and $line_of_text[5] - each one of those is just a single value, not an array, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the values to variables, and then work with them in the index.php file...

Combine lloblevel.php and ilevel.php into levels.php, and capture both values in arrays:

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("stockexport.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $ilevel_val[] = $line_of_text[3];
    $lloblevel_val[] = $line_of_text[5];

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Within index.php, add an include statements to the top of the file. This brings both arrays in to the main file.

```
<?php include 'levels.php'; ?>
```

Then, add this code where the values will print to the page:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<count($lloblevel_val);$i++) { ?>
<tr>
<td>
    <?php if ($lloblevel_val[$i] > $ilevel_val[$i]) {
        echo '<span class="highlight">'.$lloblevel_val[$i].'</span><br/>';
    } else {
        echo $lloblevel_val[$i].'<br/>'; 
    }?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php if ($ilevel_val[$i] > $lloblevel_val[$i]) {
        echo '<span class="highlight">'.$ilevel_val[$i].'</span><br/>';
    } else {
        echo $ilevel_val[$i].'<br/>'; 
    }?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php }//end for ?>
```

And finally, in your stylesheet, add a highlight class

```
.highlight {
    background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a better option for me, I have done what you have said and it dosent highlight the marked values. Could you expand on this any more for me please

Comment: What values are you getting for those two variables?

Comment: They are numbers. LLOBLevel is the current level number what I have in stock for example and ilevel is the number that is the minimum requirement of stock. So if LLOB level falls below the ilevel i want it to highlight LLOBLevel to indicate I need to order more.

Comment: If you view source, are the <mark> tags appearing? Also, are you using a stylesheet, or just doing inline styles?

Comment: I understand they are integers, but if you do: echo "lloblevel_val = ".$lloblevel_val; do you get a value?

Comment: I am using a style sheet, no inline styles.

Comment: echo "lloblevel_val = ".$lloblevel_val; just displays lloblevel_val =

Comment: I edited my answer above - take a look and make sure that the first section is happening for you - levels.php. If the values aren't getting into those variables, it doesn't matter what else we do...

Comment: lloblevel val does not display any value here is what I have so far have placed the echo "lloblevel_val = ".$lloblevel_val; at the bottom. The tables don't work either for the php to separate each column but I will sort that once I can get the correct numbers highlighted. http://www.thepccustomiser.com/stock/

Comment: I have just seen the style sheet stuff sorry, I have used exactly what you have put above and it does not show anything apart from the table now? The variables dont seem to work?

Comment: Vaporiz3, your original post did not really describe what you were trying to do here. That's why you're not getting the answer you want. What you need is a recursive solution that can handle lots and lots of values. I have revised my entire answer to use arrays instead of single variables. Start at the top of my answer again, there are changes to every file. Remember in your index.php you'll need a <table> tag before the for() loop, and a </table> tag after the loop.

Comment: I have done exactly as stated above in your revised answer and it now does not show any content.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in there. The for() loop condition was wrong - just swap out that line. It should be <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($lloblevel_val);$i++) { ?>

Comment: Still does not display any content

<table width="100%" border="1px">
<?php for ($i=0; $i<count($lloblevel_val);$i++) { ?>
<tr>
<td>
    <?php if ($lloblevel_val[$i] > $ilevel_val[$i]) {
        echo '<span class="highlight">'.$lloblevel_val[$i].'</span><br/>';
    } else {
        echo $lloblevel_val[$i].'<br/>'; 
    }?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php if ($ilevel_val[$i] > $lloblevel_val[$i]) {
        echo '<span class="highlight">'.$ilevel_val[$i].'</span><br/>';
    } else {
        echo $ilevel_val[$i].'<br/>'; 
    }?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php }//end for ?>

Comment: Then there's a problem with reading your CSV file. Inside the while() loop in levels.php, right after the $line_of_text = fgetcsv line, add  print_r($line_of_text); This will print out each array that the function produces. Then you can be sure that the values you want are $line_of_text[3] and [5].

Comment: <?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("stockexport.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
 print_r($line_of_text);
    $ilevel_val[] = $line_of_text[3];
    $lloblevel_val[] = $line_of_text[5];

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>

still has the same no content am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the file stockexport.csv in the same folder as index.php? If so, then is it a valid CSV file? I tested this code with a CSV file and it worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: can i see abit of your csv please to cross check it against mine?

Comment: First, do this for me. Just after this line: $file_handle = fopen("stockexport.csv", "r"); and before the while loop. add this little test: echo $file_handle;  If that returns FALSE, then your file is either saved in the wrong format, or in the wrong place, or your php.ini settings don't allow you to open the file.

Comment: I have placed that in the levels.php file and it didn't display anything on a refresh of the page. I have tested this on another server and still the same result. How come the csv file opened earlier with it displaying the whole file when it was single variables?

Comment: Man, we're so deep into this now. Can you edit your original question and repost your entire, current code? You could have a single comma missing, it's impossible to tell from here.

Comment: I have made the change to the question.

Comment: You're not including levels.php in your index.php file. Above the head tag, add this: <?php include 'levels.php'; ?>

Comment: Brilliant its working, I adjusted the < and > to suit for subtracting and also added a name column. The only thing is it displays the whole csv file before the actual table... how can I stop this?

Comment: I have accepted. I fixed csv problem thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate the time you have taken to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it for this structure, is to load output of each php file into javascript variable. Then parse this variables into multidimensional array. And then build table by javascript.
Second way (which is better) is to combine php files into one. Do all logic there and build html table also there by printing 'titleval1val2'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading the same csv-file in each of your php-files you have the information of each available at the point where you print them. You could simply put an if-statement around one of them and check the other, and output some html with coloured styling accordingly.

But you probably want to refactor your code and maybe spend some more time studying, because you current approach is not going to scale much beyond this kind of processing.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many possible ways to do that ...

Add `id` to your `<td>` tags

```
<td id="llob"><?php include 'lloblevel.php'; ?></td>
<td id="i"><?php include 'ilevel.php'; ?></td>
```

Add JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var llob = document.getElementById("llob").innerHTML;
var i = document.getElementById("i").innerHTML;
if( llob < i ){
    document.getElementById("llob").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just combine both of them into a single file?

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("stockexport.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
if(intval($line_of_text[3]) < intval($line_of_text[5])) { 
    print "<span class='highlight'>" . $line_of_text[3] . "</span><BR>";
    print $line_of_text[5] . "<BR>";
}
else { 
    print "<span class='highlight'>" . $line_of_text[5] . "</span><BR>";
    print $line_of_text[3] . "<BR>";
}

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Then add a class rule in the CSS file named hightlight with the background-color property.

**Note:** This would work if the values are intergers.